# Google AdWords: RelatedToKeywordSearchParameter has been deprecated - what do I replace it with?

Tags: xml, soap, google-ads-api

My AdWords iOS app generates a request to get a list of related keywords using the google AdWords API.

It is using the TargetingIdeaService API. https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService

It was working fine, using the v201109 API. This has now been replaced. The current (at time of writing this) version is v201209.

Using RelatedToKeywordSearchParameter now returns an error.

The request URL:
https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/o/v201209/TargetingIdeaService

The body (searching for words related to banana):

```
<env:Body>
    <get xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/o/v201209">
        <selector>
            <searchParameters xsi:type="RelatedToKeywordSearchParameter">
                <wsdl:keywords>
                    <cm:text>banana</cm:text>
                    <cm:matchType>EXACT</cm:matchType>
                </wsdl:keywords>
            </searchParameters>


            <ideaType>KEYWORD</ideaType>
            <requestType>IDEAS</requestType>
            <requestedAttributeTypes>COMPETITION</requestedAttributeTypes>
            <requestedAttributeTypes>CRITERION</requestedAttributeTypes>
            <wsdl:paging>
                <cm:startIndex>0</cm:startIndex>
                <cm:numberResults>50</cm:numberResults>
            </wsdl:paging>
        </selector>
    </get>
</env:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the migration documents: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/migration-v201206

RelatedToKeywordSearchParameter which takes an array of Keywords as an argument is replaced by RelatedToQuerySearchParameter which takes an array of exact keyword match query strings.